# tex4ht caption problem: undefind control sequences

Tags: tex4ht

I trying to compile my tex document with png pictures. This throw an error when I add captions to minipages. If I exclude `\caption*{#2}` and `\caption*{}` that compile.

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twodise]{book}
\usepackage[polish, russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\selectlanguage{english}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[inner=0.75in, outer=0.75in, top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}% inner=0.875in
%\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{dpfloat}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[font=Large,labelfont=Large]{caption}
\graphicspath{{"graphics/"}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\newcommandx{\spic}[3][1=0,2]{
    \clearpage
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\textheight-6pt\relax][c]{\textwidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=\textwidth]{#3}
    %\caption*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \clearpage
}
\newcommandx{\pic}[3][1=0,2]{
    \begingroup
    \clearpage
    \newpage
    \vspace*{3in}  
    \centering{\Large #2}
    \newpage
    \begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\textheight-6pt\relax][c]{\textwidth}
    \center{\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=\textwidth]{#3}}
    %\caption*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \clearpage
    \endgroup
}
\newcommandx{\lpic}[3][1=0, 2=]{
    \newpage
%   \clearpage
%   \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}[ht]
    \center{\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=0.8\textheight]{#3}}
    \caption*{#2}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
}
\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    %\addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage
}
\newcommand{\tmpx}{}
\newcommand\tmp[1]{\renewcommand{\tmpx}{#1}}
\fancypagestyle{capt}{\fancyfoot[R]{\tmpx}}
\newcommandx{\twosidepic}[2][2]{
    \clearpage
    \begingroup
    \sbox0{\includegraphics{#1}}
    \begin{figure}[p]% will be the left-side figure
    \begin{leftfullpage}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][c]{\paperwidth}
    \hspace*{-2\leftmargin}
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 {.5\wd0} 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth\relax,clip]{#1}
    \captionsetup{font = Large, labelfont=Large, singlelinecheck = false, format= hang, justification=raggedleft, labelsep=space}


% --------------PROBLEM IS HERE !!! ----------------------------------------------
%   \caption*{}


    \end{minipage}
    \end{leftfullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{fullpage}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][c]{\paperwidth}
    \hspace*{-2\leftmargin}
    \includegraphics[trim={.5\wd0} 0 0 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth\relax,clip]{#1}
    \captionsetup{font = Large, labelfont=Large, singlelinecheck = false, format= hang, labelsep=space, justification=centering} %justification=justified

% --------------PROBLEM IS HERE !!! ----------------------------------------------
%   \caption*{#2}
%

    \end{minipage}
    \end{fullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \endgroup
}
% \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancypagestyle{alim}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyfoot[C]{\arabic{page}}}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{}}

\begin{document}

\pic{_SDC2222}
\twosidepic{_SDC3333}




%\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First, please confirm really you need these much of packages?????

Comment: Yep. That is part of my document, I cut other parts to simplfy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot compile your example even with `pdflatex`, it fails with this message:

```
dpfloat moved a leftpage float from page 3. ! Output loop---100
consecutive dead cycles. \AP@clearpage ...e \m@ne {}\vbox {}\penalty
-\@Mi
```

So I've created a simpler example that shows the same issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image.png}
    \captionsetup{font = Large, labelfont=Large, singlelinecheck = false, format= hang, labelsep=space, justification=centering} %justification=justified
  \caption*{Hello, caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This file causes TeX4ht to fail. To fix that, we need to update two support files.

First one is `usepackage.4ht`. This file is used to patch packages at the moment when they are loaded:

```
% usepackage.4ht (2020-04-23-13:56), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2003-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2020 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2020-04-23-13:56}

   \def\:temp{tex4ht}\ifx \:temp\@currname
   \:warning{\string\usepackage{tex4ht} again?}
   \def\:temp#1htex4ht.def,tex4ht.sty#2!*?: {\def\:temp{#2}}
\expandafter\:temp \@filelist htex4ht.def,tex4ht.sty!*?: %
\ifx \:temp\empty  \else
   \:warning{if
    \string\RequirePackage[tex4ht]{hyperref} or
    \string\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref} was
    used try instead, repectively,
    \string\RequirePackage{hyperref} or
    \string\usepackage{hyperref}}
\fi

\fi
\gdef\a:usepackage{\use:package cleveref,xr,xr-hyper,eso-pic,showframe,expl3,savetrees,biblatex,xeCJK,polyglossia,fontspec,tikz,pdfbase,caption,graphics,xcolor,imakeidx,minted,fancyhdr,,!*?: }
\gdef\use:package#1,{%
   \if :#1:\def\:temp##1!*?: {}\else
      \def\:temp{#1}\ifx \@currname\:temp
             \def\:temp##1!*?: {\input usepackage.4ht  }%
      \else \let\:temp=\use:package \fi
   \fi \:temp}
\def\:temp{cleveref}\ifx\@currname\:temp
\let\HyOrg@addtoreset\@addtoreset
\fi
\def\:temp{xr}\ifx \@currname\:temp
   \:AtEndOfPackage{\let\XR:\XR@
   \def\XR@[#1]#2{%
    \Configure{AtBeginDocument}{\XR:[#1]{#2}}{}}%
}

\fi
\def\:temp{xr-hyper}\ifx \@currname\:temp
   \:AtEndOfPackage{\let\XR:\XR@
    \def\XR@[#1][#2]#3{%
      \AtBeginDocument{\XR:[#1][#2]{#3}}
    }%
}

\fi
\def\:temp{eso-pic}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:dontusepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\AddToShipoutPicture{\@ifstar{}{}}
\let\AddToShipoutPictureBG\AddToShipoutPicture
\let\AddToShipoutPictureFG\AddToShipoutPicture
\fi
\def\:temp{showframe}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:dontusepackage{showframe}
\fi
\def\:temp{expl3}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\ifdefined\XeTeXversion%
\xenunidelblock{Latin-expl3}%
\:AtEndOfPackage{\xeuniuseblock{Latin-expl3}}
\fi
\fi
\def\:temp{savetrees}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:dontusepackage{savetrees}
\fi
\def\:temp{biblatex}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \def\blx@mknoautolang{%
    \blx@lbxinput{\blx@languagename}%
    {}{}%
  }%
  \def\blx@lbxinput@iii#1#2{%
  \global\csundef{blx@lng@#2}%
  \:IfFileExists{#1.lbx}
    {\blx@lbxinput@iv{#2}{#1}{language '#2' -> '#1'}}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@suffmaptried@#2}
      {}
      {\blx@warning@noline{%
          File '#1.lbx' not found!\MessageBreak
          Ignoring mapping '#2' -> '#1'}%
       \global\cslet{blx@suffmaptried@#2}\@empty}%
     \blx@lbxinput@iv{#2}{#2}{language '#2'}}}

}
\fi
\def\:temp{xeCJK}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:dontusepackage{xeCJK}
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \RequirePackage{fontspec}
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\setCJKmainfont{o m o}{}
\let\setCJKsansfont\setCJKmainfont
\let\setCJKmonofont\setCJKmainfont

\DeclareDocumentCommand\setCJKfamilyfont {m o m }{}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\newCJKfontfamily {o m o m}{\expandafter\gdef\csname #2\endcsname{\relax}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\xeCJKsetup{m}{}
% }
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xeuniuseblock{CJK}
}
\fi
\def\:temp{polyglossia}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\ExplSyntaxOn
\:AtEndOfPackage{

\cs_set_eq:NN\orig_polyglossia@keys_define_lang:n\polyglossia@keys_define_lang:n
\cs_set_protected:Npn \polyglossia@keys_define_lang:n #1 {
  \orig_polyglossia@keys_define_lang:n{#1}
  \keys_define:nn {polyglossia}{
    #1 / direction
    .  code:n = {}
  }
}
\def\RequireBidi{}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\fi
\def\:temp{fontspec}\ifx \@currname\:temp
  \ifdefined\fontspec
    \:dontusepackage{fontspec}
  \else
    \input usepackage-fontspec.4ht
  \fi
\fi
\def\:temp{tikz}\ifx \@currname\:temp
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
\let\use:tikzlibrary\usetikzlibrary
\def\find:externalize#1external#2\@nil{%
\if\relax#2\relax\else
  \let\tikz:externalize\tikzexternalize
  \renewcommand\tikzexternalize[1][]{\tikz:externalize[##1,mode=only graphics]}
    \tikzset{%
      tex4ht inc/.style={%
        /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
          \includegraphics[]{####1.pdf}%
        }%
      }
    }
    \tikzset{tex4ht inc}
  \fi
}
\append:defI\use@@tikzlibrary{\find:externalize##1external\@nil}%
}
\fi
\def\:temp{pdfbase}\ifx\@currname\:temp
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \let\old:outputpage\@outputpage
  \def\@outputpage{\old:outputpage{}}
}
\fi
\def\:temp{caption}\ifx\@currname\:temp
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \long\def\caption@If@Package@Loaded#1[#2]#3#4{}
  %\renewcommand*\caption@redefine{}
    \renewcommand*\caption@redefine{%
      \let\caption\caption@caption
      \let\@caption\caption@@caption%
  }%
}
\fi
\def\:temp{graphics}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \ifdefined\XeTeXversion
    \PassOptionsToPackage{dvips}{graphics}
  \fi
\fi
\def\:temp{xcolor}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \ifdefined\XeTeXversion
    \PassOptionsToPackage{dvips}{xcolor}
  \fi
\fi
\def\:temp{imakeidx}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \PassOptionsToPackage{noautomatic}{imakeidx}
\fi
\def\:temp{minted}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \:AtEndOfPackage{%
    \define@booleankey{minted@opt@g}{breaklines}{}{}{}%
  }
\fi
\def\:temp{fancyhdr}\ifx\@currname\:temp
  \:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \def\ps@fancy{}%
  }
\fi


\endinput
```

The important part is this:

```
\def\:temp{caption}\ifx\@currname\:temp
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \long\def\caption@If@Package@Loaded#1[#2]#3#4{}
  \renewcommand*\caption@redefine{%
      \let\caption\caption@caption
      \let\@caption\caption@@caption%
  }%
}
\fi
```

This fixes the fatal error.

Next, we need to provide customized definitions to correctly support the starred version of `\caption` command.

Save this as `caption.4ht`:

```
% caption.4ht (2020-05-22-14:40), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2007-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2020 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\let\sv:toclof\toclof
\def\toclof#1#2#3{%
   \bgroup
     \def\a:TocLink##1##2##3##4{\gdef\:temp{##4}}%
     #2%
   \egroup
   \ifx \:temp\empty \else
      \sv:toclof{#1}{#2}{#3}%
   \fi
}
\let\lof:ConfigureToc\ConfigureToc
\long\def\ConfigureToc#1#2#3#4#5{%
   \lof:ConfigureToc{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
   \def\:temp{#1}\def\:tempa{lof}\ifx \:temp\:tempa
      \let\toc:lof\toclof
      \def\toclof##1##2##3{%
         \bgroup
           \def\a:TocLink####1####2####3####4{\gdef\:temp{####4}}%
           ##2%
         \egroup
         \ifx\:temp\empty\else
            \toc:lof {##1}{##2}{##3}%
         \fi
   }\fi%
}

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \caption@make@above%
  \cptA:\caption@@make{\cap:ref{#1}\if :#1:\else\cptB:\fi}{\cptC:#2}\cptD:%
  \caption@make@below%
}

\Hinput{caption}
\endinput
```

It contains modified version of the `\@makecaption` command:

```
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \caption@make@above%
  \cptA:\caption@@make{\cap:ref{#1}\if :#1:\else\cptB:\fi}{\cptC:#2}\cptD:%
  \caption@make@below%
}
```

The `\cptA:` and other commands that contain the `:` character in their names are used to insert HTML tags.

This is the result:

[image]

These files also work for your original files, but I cannot tell if the result is correct, as I cannot compile the PDF version.

Comment: Thank you, thats works. Error wich you get while pdf convertation my document caused by dpfloat, which need even page. Just insert \blankpage before \twosidepic to fix it, if you are interested.