# includegraphics does not clip pictures with ebook conversion

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook

This is continuation of my efforts to create an eBook from LaTeX, the previous is here: [tex4ht caption problem: undefind control sequences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545582/tex4ht-caption-problem-undefind-control-sequences?noredirect=1#comment1378203_545582)

When converting my document to eBook, the command

```
\includegraphics[trim=0 0 {.5\wd0} 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth\relax,clip]{#1}
```

does not clip my pictures, whereas a normal (pdf) conversion does.

Any suggestion?

And a second question, why does ebook conversion repeat my document twice?

Code of document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twodise]{book}
\usepackage[polish, russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\selectlanguage{english}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[inner=0.75in, outer=0.75in, top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}% inner=0.875in
%\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{dpfloat}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[font=Large,labelfont=Large]{caption}
\graphicspath{{"graphics/"}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\newcommandx{\spic}[3][1=0,2]{
    \clearpage
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\textheight-6pt\relax][c]{\textwidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=\textwidth]{#3}
    %\caption*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \clearpage
}
\newcommandx{\pic}[3][1=0,2]{
    \begingroup
    \clearpage
    \newpage
    \vspace*{3in}  
    \centering{\Large #2}
    \newpage
    \begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\textheight-6pt\relax][c]{\textwidth}
    \center{\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=\textwidth]{#3}}
    %\caption*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \clearpage
    \endgroup
}
\newcommandx{\lpic}[3][1=0, 2=]{
    \newpage
%   \clearpage
%   \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}[ht]
    \center{\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=0.8\textheight]{#3}}
    \caption*{#2}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
}
\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    %\addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage
}
\newcommand{\tmpx}{}
\newcommand\tmp[1]{\renewcommand{\tmpx}{#1}}
\fancypagestyle{capt}{\fancyfoot[R]{\tmpx}}
\newcommandx{\twosidepic}[2][2]{
    \clearpage
    \begingroup
    \sbox0{\includegraphics{#1}}
    \begin{figure}[p]% will be the left-side figure
    \begin{leftfullpage}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][c]{\paperwidth}
    \hspace*{-2\leftmargin}
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 {.5\wd0} 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth\relax,clip]{#1}
    \captionsetup{font = Large, labelfont=Large, singlelinecheck = false, format= hang, justification=raggedleft, labelsep=space}


%   \caption*{}


    \end{minipage}
    \end{leftfullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{fullpage}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][c]{\paperwidth}
    \hspace*{-2\leftmargin}
    \includegraphics[trim={.5\wd0} 0 0 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth\relax,clip]{#1}
    \captionsetup{font = Large, labelfont=Large, singlelinecheck = false, format= hang, labelsep=space, justification=centering} %justification=justified

%   \caption*{#2}
%

    \end{minipage}
    \end{fullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \endgroup
}
% \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancypagestyle{alim}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyfoot[C]{\arabic{page}}}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{}}

\begin{document}

\pic{_SDC2222}
\blankpage
\twosidepic{_SDC3333}




%\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

Following comments, here's the config file I use:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{@TITLE}{\let\titlefont\relax}
\Configure{graphics*}  
    {pdf}  
    {\Needs{"convert '\csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf'  
                         '\csname Gin@base\endcsname.jpg'"}%  
    \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.jpg}%  
    \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.jpg}
    }  
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Following instructions below I edit my devide my file up to mypic.sty, mypic.4ht and mydocument.tex:

mypic.sty:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dpfloat}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage[font=Large,labelfont=Large]{caption}
\graphicspath{{"graphics/"}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}

\newcommandx{\spic}[3][1=0,2]{
    \clearpage
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\textheight-6pt\relax][c]{\textwidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=\textwidth]{#3}
    %\caption*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \clearpage
}
\newcommandx{\pic}[3][1=0,2]{
    \begingroup
    \clearpage
    \newpage
    \vspace*{3in}  
    \centering{\Large #2}
    \newpage
    \begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\textheight-6pt\relax][c]{\textwidth}
    \center{\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=\textwidth]{#3}}
    %\caption*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \clearpage
    \endgroup
}
\newcommandx{\lpic}[3][1=0, 2=]{
    \newpage
%   \clearpage
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}[ht]
    \center{\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=0.8\textheight]{#3}}
    \caption*{#2}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
}
\newcommandx{\twosidepic}[2][2]{
    \clearpage
    \begingroup
    \sbox0{\includegraphics{#1}}
    \begin{figure}[p]% will be the left-side figure
    \begin{leftfullpage}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][c]{\paperwidth}
    \hspace*{-2\leftmargin}
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 {.5\wd0} 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth\relax,clip]{#1}
    \captionsetup{font = Large, labelfont=Large, singlelinecheck = false, format= hang, justification=raggedleft, labelsep=space}
    \caption*{}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{leftfullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{fullpage}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][c]{\paperwidth}
    \hspace*{-2\leftmargin}
    \includegraphics[trim={.5\wd0} 0 0 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth\relax,clip]{#1}
    \captionsetup{font = Large, labelfont=Large, singlelinecheck = false, format= hang, labelsep=space, justification=centering} %justification=justified
    \caption*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{fullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \endgroup
}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{}}
\newcommand\trimimage[1]{%
}
\endinput
```

mypic.4ht

```
\NewConfigure{twosidepic}{2}
\renewcommandx\twosidepic[2][2]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP%
\a:twosidepic%
\begin{figure}%
\openin15=#1-01.jpg
\ifeof15
\Needs{"convert "#1.jpg"  -crop 50\%x100\% +repage "#1-\%02d.jpg""}
\else
\includegraphics{#1-00.jpg}%
\includegraphics{#1-01.jpg}%
\fi
\caption*{#2}%
\end{figure}%
\b:twosidepic\par%
}
```

mydocument.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twodise]{book}
\usepackage[polish, russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\selectlanguage{english}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[inner=0.75in, outer=0.75in, top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}% inner=0.875in
%\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mypic}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em} % changes vertical space between paragraphs
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % sets indent to zero

\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    %\addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage
}
\newcommand{\tmpx}{}
\newcommand\tmp[1]{\renewcommand{\tmpx}{#1}}
\fancypagestyle{capt}{\fancyfoot[R]{\tmpx}}

% \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancypagestyle{alim}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyfoot[C]{\arabic{page}}}

\begin{document}

\pic{1}
\blankpage
\twosidepic{2}

%\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Confirm which TeX you are using, i.e., `LaTeX`, `PDFLaTeX`, etc.?

Comment: I am using TexLive with win cmd "tex4ebook  book.tex"

Comment: what do you mean by " repeat my document twice?" Is the document contents included twice in the Epub file? Or do you mean number of compilations? `tex4ebook` does three compilations by default, you can require only one compilation using the `-m draft` option.

Comment: This is exacly "document contents included twice in the Epub file"

Comment: repetition of the contents of the document occurs only in the ePub file, not HTML.

Comment: maybe it is just issue with your ebook viewer? I don't see the content twice in the generated Epub file

Comment: Yes, I used sumatraPDF and seems its not the best choice for ePub. Thanks. Repeating issue solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, your command `\twosdepic` splits an image to two facing sides, in order to occupy the full size of the opened book. My first reaction is that this feature isn't that useful in ebook, because you usually view only one page at once, so you will not see the image in the full size if you split it over two pages. So the real solution is to redefine your macro for TeX4ht to include the image only once, at the full size.

If you really want to clip the image (and I really think it is not a good idea in your case), you have two options:

- prepare two images, each one half of the original image and include them. This can be done automatically using Imagemagick. The good thing about this solution is that it should work in any Ebook reader.
- use CSS to clip images. note that Ebook readers are notorious for poor CSS support, so you may end with two images at the full size rendered by the reader.

Anyway, first thing I would do is to extract your custom commands from your TeX file to a standalone package. For example `mypackages.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypackages}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{xargs}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{dpfloat}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\newcommandx{\spic}[3][1=0,2]{
    \clearpage
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\textheight-6pt\relax][c]{\textwidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=\textwidth]{#3}
    %\caption*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \clearpage
}
\newcommandx{\pic}[3][1=0,2]{
    \begingroup
    \clearpage
    \newpage
    \vspace*{3in}
    \centering{\Large #2}
    \newpage
    \begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\textheight-6pt\relax][c]{\textwidth}
    \center{\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=\textwidth]{#3}}
    %\caption*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \clearpage
    \endgroup
}
\newcommandx{\lpic}[3][1=0, 2=]{
    \newpage
%   \clearpage
%   \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}[ht]
    \center{\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=0.8\textheight]{#3}}
    \caption*{#2}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
}
\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    %\addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage
}
\newcommand{\tmpx}{}
\newcommand\tmp[1]{\renewcommand{\tmpx}{#1}}
\fancypagestyle{capt}{\fancyfoot[R]{\tmpx}}
\newcommandx{\twosidepic}[2][2]{
    \clearpage
    \begingroup
    \sbox0{\includegraphics{#1}}
    \begin{figure}[p]% will be the left-side figure
    \begin{leftfullpage}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][c]{\paperwidth}
    \hspace*{-2\leftmargin}
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 {.5\wd0} 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth\relax,clip]{#1}
    \captionsetup{font = Large, labelfont=Large, singlelinecheck = false, format= hang, justification=raggedleft, labelsep=space}


%   \caption*{}


    \end{minipage}
    \end{leftfullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{fullpage}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][c]{\paperwidth}
    \hspace*{-2\leftmargin}
    \includegraphics[trim={.5\wd0} 0 0 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth\relax,clip]{#1}
    \captionsetup{font = Large, labelfont=Large, singlelinecheck = false, format= hang, labelsep=space, justification=centering} %justification=justified

%   \caption*{#2}
%

    \end{minipage}
    \end{fullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \endgroup
}
% \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancypagestyle{alim}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyfoot[C]{\arabic{page}}}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{}}

\newcommand\trimimage[1]{%
}
\endinput
```

This makes your TeX file easier to handle and more importantly, it enables us to write TeX4ht configuration for it. The file `mypackages.4ht` will be used each time you use your package. The basic form can look like this:

```
\NewConfigure{twosidepic}{2}
\renewcommandx\twosidepic[2][2]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP%
\a:twosidepic%
\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics{#1}%
\caption*{#2}%
\end{figure}%
\b:twosidepic\par%
}
```

It just simplifies your `\twosidepic` command to contain only the bare minimum, as most of your original code isn't useful in the conversion process at all, it just handles the visual appearance in the PDF file. It includes the image at full size. The `\NewConfigure{twosidepic}{2}` defines two new commands, `\a:twosidepic` and `\b:twosidepic`. They can be used to insert specific HTML code from TeX4ht configuration file. We don't use them yet in this version, but it is nice to have them available when we need them.

Here is a sample file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mypackages}
\begin{document}
\twosidepic{example-image}
\end{document}
```

This is the PDF version:

[image]

And this is HTML:

[image]

Here is configuration file for the image splitting method:

```
\NewConfigure{twosidepic}{2}
\renewcommandx\twosidepic[2][2]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP%
\a:twosidepic%
\begin{figure}%
\openin15=#1-01.png
\ifeof15
\Needs{"convert "#1.png"  -crop 50\%x100\% +repage "#1-\%02d.png""}
\else
\includegraphics{#1-00.png}%
\includegraphics{#1-01.png}%
\fi
\caption*{#2}%
\end{figure}%
\b:twosidepic\par%
}
```

It uses Imagemagick to split the image to two parts. It is requested using this command:

```
\Needs{"convert "#1.png"  -crop 50\%x100\% +repage "#1-\%02d.png""}
```

The image conversion is requested only if the cropped images doesn't exist, which is checked using:

```
\openin15=#1-01.png
\ifeof15
```

Note that we expect images to be in the PNG format, you can change it to something different, depending on your use case.

When the image exists, images for both left and right sides are inserted.

Note that this method needs two compilation steps by `tex4ebook`. First invocation will generate the images, they can be included only in the second run.

This is the result:

[image]

The last method, with CSS, will need more complicated and I have go out, so I may try it latter.

Edit:

Here is `mypic.4ht` version with support for `\graphicspath`:

```
\NewConfigure{twosidepic}{2}
\renewcommandx\twosidepic[2][2]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP%
\a:twosidepic%
\begin{figure}%
\def\my@ext{.jpg}
\ifx\Ginput@path\@undefined
  \let\Ginput@path\input@path
\fi
\let\input@path\Ginput@path%
\@iffileonpath{#1\my@ext}{
  \typeout{file found: \@filef@und}%
  \expandafter\filename@parse\expandafter{\@filef@und}
  \edef\base@name{\filename@area\filename@base}
  \openin15=\base@name-00\my@ext\relax
  \ifeof15
    \Needs{"convert \base@name\my@ext"  -crop 50\%x100\% +repage \base@name-\%02d\my@ext""}
  \else
    \includegraphics{\base@name-00\my@ext}%
    \includegraphics{\base@name-01\my@ext}%
  \fi
}{\typeout{Image not found}}
\caption*{#2}%
\end{figure}%
\b:twosidepic\par%
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. You are right, it is usually not very useful to use split images on an e-book. But you can want to use it if, for example, you present a map with small details. In addition, some self-publishing services prefere doc and have some restrictions with PDF format. For example, there is a limit on the size of upload files, and you cannot upload the entire book. You can upload a two-part book and combine them online, but not when you use PDF. In addition, Amazon sometimes has problems with pdf for some reason or for some bugs.

Comment: So, you can want to use eBook format to upload a paperbook.

Comment: I would like to avoid split photos with my own hands for two reasons. 

Firstly, this is a little bit unwanted fun with it. Imagine you have 100 similar pictures and you need to split 20 of them. They have no differences in names, and you need to look for them in the folder with your own eyes. Believe me, you do not want this. Then you have to move them to another folder, split and get them back. What if later you decide to split another one photo?

Comment: Another reason is that you need to have different copies of these pictures for the e-book and the paperbook version. If you use the html or eBook format to upload your paper book to a self-publishing service, you may still want to have an unsplitted version of the images to use in your e-book.

Comment: it is more convenient to have one set of graphics and two of tex files for a book and an ebook than to have one tex file and two sets of graphics. Is it possible to use splitting with mk2ht?

Comment: @Vladimir OK, I will try to come with the CSS solution. Unfortunately, there is no  direct link between Graphicx's package options and the necessary CSS, so I think I won't support arbitrary clipping. But simpler clipping, like clipping  half of the image should be possible.

Comment: thank you, but before you start, does it will be possible to convert that html-css to odt or doc? if not, then I am afraid that this may not be entirely useful for me since I do not think that the online viewers of the above services will css, if they cant cope with pdf

Comment: Tell me please, is this possible? So that during compilation, the images are cropped and cropped are inserted, but not insert uncropped images with command to crop it.

Comment: @Vladimir OK, so the CSS method is not useful at all for you. I've edited my answer with automatic image splitting solution.

Comment: Thank you, but it still does not work for me. I edited my post to show how does il looks like (last 3 code blocks). I devide tex file as you said , but with a little corrects (I hope that is no a reason why it does not work), change png to jpg extentions in 4ht file. Document compile as pdf nicely, but does not split picture when compile to ePub. Pictures *-00.jpg and *-01.jpg does not spawn at /graphics folder.

Comment: @Vladimir the issue is with `\graphicspath`. It is not that easy to support it. I've updated my answer with possible solution.,

Comment: Does not work also. When I change mypic.4ht file I get same result: ePub file with 1.jpg picture (pic{1}). When I add pictures (1.jpg, 2.jpg) near tex file, get the same. But if I delete %\graphicspath{{"graphics/"}} line, I get an error:
 ! Undefined control sequence.
\@iffileonpath ...fter :\expandafter =\input@path
                                                  \do {\openin \@inputcheck ...
l.45

Comment: Previous version of mypic.4ht and without \graphicspath{{"graphics/"}} line did not split images also.

Comment: @Vladimir do you have Imagemagick installed?

Comment: Oh, I thought it was installed with latex. I installed it and now I have the files -00.jpg and -01.jpg in the graphics / folder. But still they are not in ePub and HTML files of the book.
I changed Needs to \Needs{"E:/Books/ImageMagick/magick.exe convert \base@name\my@ext"  -crop 50\%x100\% +repage \base@name-\%02d\my@ext""} to make Imagemagick work.

Comment: Sorry, its seems WORK! I just have to start compiling several times. Thank. I will try and write here tomorrow how things are going with my main document. The test document looks good.

Comment: Thank you a LOT. I spent a lot of time on this and, if nothing had worked, it would have killed me. Now I have a tool that works. I have only a few cosmetic questions (3 questions).
I start Tex4Ht through the windows terminal, is it possible to start Tex4Ht with the commands I need through TexWork? Can this be done so that if ImageMagic were to be used, Tex4Ht would be launched twice? Tex4Ht creates 16 service files at compile time, can I somehow delete them after compilation or have Tex4Ht create a temp folder and these files are created in this folder?

Comment: @Vladimir I've updated the `.4ht` file to work without `\graphicspath`. I am happy it works now.

Comment: @Vladimir I think it would be best to create a Makefile that would handle both PDF and Epub version of your document automatically. It can also delete the temporary files. Note that they may be needed in the compilation, so it is good to remove them only when you don't really need to compile your document anymore.

Comment: @Vladimir I don't know what version of Make is available on Windows, but I think it should be possible to install it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it would be great. But is it possible to find out through Make whether ImagrMagic was used or not?

Comment: I mean, compilation can be run twice every time, but it is not a smart way. If it possible to run recompilation just in case when ImageMagic was used, that will be more clever. But, if it can not be done, it is not necessary that you write it in Make, I can write it myself in bat (and I will post my script here, if someone needs it). Also bat - scripts can delete temporally files.

Comment: @Vladimir it is really not necessary to run every compilation two times, it is necessary only when a new image is added. Once there are converted files, they can be reused.

Comment: I already understood this, but I do not want to remember this. I want to call the script once and have it compile the book as many times as needed.

Comment: @Vladimir OK, then you can use the two invocations. You can use the `-m draft` option to make the compilation faster.

Answer (score 1):

From your `MWE`, hope you are using the images are in .pdf and .png format, if yes, then try with the below:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
  \Configure{graphics*}  
         {pdf}  
         {\Needs{"convert '\csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf'  
                               '\csname Gin@base\endcsname.png'"}%  
          \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}%  
          \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}
         }  
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: I use images in jpg format. I replace "png" to "jpg" in your example, but it does not help me.
I add myconfig.cfg version in start post.