# The script for printing pictures on the page spread

Tags: tex4ht

This is continuation of [includegraphics does not clip pictures with ebook conversion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545787/includegraphics-does-not-clip-pictures-with-ebook-conversion/545809?noredirect=1#comment1380506_545809)

In my last topic I was shown a script that, using an external ImageMagic program, divides an image into two parts and puts them into a document. But I used the dpfloat package for this, which, weakly, works poorly with Tex4ht.

The problem is showed on the picture below:

[image]

I dont know what is a reason of that, but I think it is a dpfloat issue. So, I have two ways: make dpfloats works (I dont know how???) or get rid of it. I can get rid of dpfloats, because I already have splitted pictures from ImageMagick. Need just pust them as normal pictures, maybe with smaller margines to make them bleed. But when I tried to do this, Tex4Ht insert same (left) half of picture on both side. I tried to do myself, but I dont undestand how does it works.

my files, if need it:

mypic.4ht:

```
\NewConfigure{twosidepic}{2}
\renewcommandx\twosidepic[2][2]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP%
\a:twosidepic%
\begin{figure}%
\def\my@ext{.jpg}
\ifx\Ginput@path\@undefined
  \let\Ginput@path\input@path
\fi
\let\input@path\Ginput@path%
\@iffileonpath{#1\my@ext}{
  \typeout{file found: \@filef@und}%
  \expandafter\filename@parse\expandafter{\@filef@und}
  \edef\base@name{\filename@area\filename@base}
  \openin15=\base@name-00\my@ext\relax
  \ifeof15
    \Needs{"convert \base@name\my@ext"  -crop 50\%x100\% +repage \base@name-\%02d\my@ext""}
  \else
    \includegraphics{\base@name-00\my@ext}%
    \includegraphics{\base@name-01\my@ext}%
  \fi
}{\typeout{Image not found}}
\caption*{#2}%
\end{figure}%
\b:twosidepic\par%
}
```

mypic.sty:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dpfloat}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage[font=Large,labelfont=Large]{caption}
\graphicspath{{"graphics/"}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}

\newcommandx{\spic}[3][1=0,2]{
    \clearpage
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\textheight-6pt\relax][c]{\textwidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=\textwidth]{#3}
    %\caption*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \clearpage
}
\newcommandx{\pic}[3][1=0,2]{
    \begingroup
    \clearpage
    \newpage
    \vspace*{3in}  
    \centering{\Large #2}
    \newpage
    \begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\textheight-6pt\relax][c]{\textwidth}
    \center{\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=\textwidth]{#3}}
    %\caption*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \clearpage
    \endgroup
}
\newcommandx{\lpic}[3][1=0, 2=]{
    \newpage
%   \clearpage
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}[ht]
    \center{\includegraphics[angle=#1, width=0.8\textheight]{#3}}
    \caption*{#2}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
}
\newcommandx{\twosidepic}[2][2]{
    \clearpage
    \begingroup
    \sbox0{\includegraphics{#1}}
    \begin{figure}[p]% will be the left-side figure
    \begin{leftfullpage}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][c]{\paperwidth}
    \hspace*{-2\leftmargin}
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 {.5\wd0} 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth\relax,clip]{#1}
    \captionsetup{font = Large, labelfont=Large, singlelinecheck = false, format= hang, justification=raggedleft, labelsep=space}
    \caption*{}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{leftfullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{fullpage}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][c]{\paperwidth}
    \hspace*{-2\leftmargin}
    \includegraphics[trim={.5\wd0} 0 0 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth\relax,clip]{#1}
    \captionsetup{font = Large, labelfont=Large, singlelinecheck = false, format= hang, labelsep=space, justification=centering} %justification=justified
    \caption*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{fullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \endgroup
}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{}}
\newcommand\trimimage[1]{%
}
\endinput
```

mydocument.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twodise]{book}
\usepackage[polish, russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\selectlanguage{english}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[inner=0.75in, outer=0.75in, top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}% inner=0.875in
%\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mypic}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em} % changes vertical space between paragraphs
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % sets indent to zero

\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    %\addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage
}
\newcommand{\tmpx}{}
\newcommand\tmp[1]{\renewcommand{\tmpx}{#1}}
\fancypagestyle{capt}{\fancyfoot[R]{\tmpx}}

% \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancypagestyle{alim}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyfoot[C]{\arabic{page}}}

\begin{document}

\pic{1}
\blankpage
\twosidepic{2}

%\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

Comment: so you want to get rid of the `dbfloat` package in your .sty file? I think you can keep it here, I would just simplify the image inclusion in the '\twosidepic` command. You can use the generated half images instead of trimming of the one big picture.

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks for answer, I edit my post.